# How to deallocate Ada Record from CPP

Tags: c++, ada, gnat

I am attempting to free a heap allocated Ada tagged record from cpp. I have used the code [AdacoreU](https://github.com/AdaCoreU/Courses/tree/master/lectures/04_Mixed_Language_Programming_In_Ada/03_Ada_and_C%2B%2B/sources/exporting_ada_tagged_types) as a starting place.

I receive the following error when running the code below.

```
20
double free or corruption (out)

raised PROGRAM_ERROR : unhandled signal
```

Am I overthinking things? Do I need an Ada based deallocation mechanism.

What is my real end goal? I would like to use dynamic libraries to create a plugin infrastructure where each library is its own factory for a given type. Something along the lines of [boost dll](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/doc/html/boost_dll/tutorial.html) but with ada based dynamic libraries.

Modified Code below:

main.cpp

```
  1 #include <iostream>
  2 #include "animal.h"
  3 
  4 extern "C" {
  5     void adainit (void);
  6     void adafinal (void);
  7     Animal* new_animal();
  8     void del_animal(Animal *);
  9 }
 10 
 11 int main(void) {
 12     adainit();
 13     Animal* A = new_animal();
 14     std::cout << A->age() << std::endl;
 15     //delete A;   
 16     del_animal(A);
 17     adafinal();
 18     return 0;
 19 };
```

alib.ads

```
  1 
  2 with Interfaces.C;
  3 
  4 package ALib is
  5 
  6     type Animal is tagged record
  7         The_Age : Interfaces.C.int;
  8     end record;
  9     pragma Convention (CPP, Animal);
 10 
 11     type Animal_Class_Access is access Animal'Class;
 12 
 13     function New_Animal return access Animal'Class;
 14     pragma Export(CPP, New_Animal);
 15 
 16     procedure Del_Animal (this : in out Animal_Class_Access);
 17     pragma Export(CPP, Del_Animal);
 18 
 19     function Age(X : Animal) return Interfaces.C.int;
 20     pragma Export(CPP, Age);
 21 
 22 end ALib;
```

alib.adb

```
  1 with ada.unchecked_deallocation;
  2 
  3 package body ALib is
  4 
  5     function New_Animal
  6         return access Animal'Class is
  7     begin
  8         return new Animal'(The_Age => 20);
  9     end New_Animal;
 10 
 11 
 12     procedure Del_Animal (this : in out Animal_Class_Access) is
 13         procedure Free is new ada.unchecked_deallocation(Animal'Class, Animal_Class_Access);
 14     begin
 15         Free(this);
 16         --null;
 17     end Del_Animal;
 18 
 19     function Age(X : Animal)
 20         return Interfaces.C.int is
 21     begin
 22         return X.The_Age;
 23     end Age;
 24 
 25 end ALib;
~
```

other resources used as a starting point

[3.11.3.5 Interfacing with C++ at the Class Level](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn/Interfacing-with-C_002b_002b-at-the-Class-Level.html)

What have I attempted:

- Used various combinations of the type and access type when attempting to create the Free procedure

  - Animal, type Animal_Access is access Animal
  - Animal'Class, type Animal_Class_Access is access Animal'Class
  - Animal, type Animal_Access is access Animal'Class
- I was at some point under the impression that I should be using system address for the pointers to the Animal object as either part of the return on New_Animal and as the argument to Del_Animal

What did I expect:

I expected to clean up Ada heap objects from Ada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the `in out` parameter to `Del_Animal` and its mapping to the C world.

Your intention with `Del_Animal` is that it should behave like `Ada.Unchecked_Deallocation`, in other words that the parameter is set to `null` (or `0`!) after the call, but that means that what you have to pass is the *address* of the actual.

That is,

```c
void del_animal(Animal**);
```

called as

```c
del_animal(&A);
```

See [ARM B3(68)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-B-3.html#p68).

Comment: Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: As far as I know this _is_ the way of doing this. What would strike you as "better"?

Comment: There isn't anything in particular that would strike me as better. I had just assumed I was doing something in a non-typical way and that I could have 'better' results by following some other kind of pattern.